# Mysql wont insert into database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

As far as I can see my SQL code is formatted correctly, it seems to just be refusing to insert into the database.
this is my code:

```
 INSERT INTO `writings`(`cover`, `pages`) VALUES(['test'], [10]);
```

i also tried

```
INSERT INTO `writings`(cover, pages) VALUES(['test'], [10]);
```

&

```
INSERT INTO `writings`(cover, pages) VALUES('test', 10);
```

I encounter this error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['test'], [10])' at line 1 "

table name is correct, aswell as column names.
Any help would be fantastic! :)

Comment: MySQL does not use `[]` around values. Your third query should work fine...

Comment: If you get an error for the third one then include it in the question, the two first are incorrect so forget about them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First two queries are incorrect as mentioned above.
 
Third query is absolutely correct and must work. If it doesn't, try using INSERT ... SET syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `writings` SET cover = 'test', pages = 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out on the comment

> MySQL does not use [] around values

So you should try this way

```
   INSERT INTO `writings`(`cover`, `pages`) VALUES('test', 10);
```

OR **if you want the cover and pages value as an string of array notation**

```
INSERT INTO `writings`(`cover`, `pages`) VALUES("['test']", "[10]");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO writings(cover, pages) VALUES('test', 10);
```

This is worked for inserting data in mysql. Basic syntax problem in your query, nothing else. Make sure table name and field name is proper match with database & values are of same datatype you mention while created table.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this :

Sql Query:

```
INSERT INTO writings (cover, pages) VALUES ('test', 10);
```

Comment: This would error as `test` is not a valid identifier. You need to quote it because it’s a string.